# Prevent Copy the files from the server to server

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, http, directadmin

I have dedicated server, control panel is DirectAdmin and OS is linux. Using the [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) `copy ( "https://example.com/file.mp3" , string $dest)` command in PHP, The file can be copied. How can I prevent? Prevent copying server to server this link for example: `https://example.com/file.mp3`

Comment: If the file is publicly accessible through a web-server, anybody can copy it anywhere.

Comment: @jeroen There is no way?

Comment: move it outside the root directory of the web server.

Comment: @Federkun For example, which directory?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question on ServerFault (assuming you use Apache2):

[Apache .htaccess file to restrict access to file except when loaded from a certain url](https://serverfault.com/questions/264399/apache-htaccess-file-to-restrict-access-to-file-except-when-loaded-from-a-certa)

or this:

[control Apache referrer to restrict downloads in htaccess file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88874/control-apache-referrer-to-restrict-downloads-in-htaccess-file)